# using local storage saved value as a text in a root text

Tags: extjs, tree, local-storage, store

I have a treeView in my extjs View, in which I need to give the the value of a local storage variable as the root name.The value to the local storage is fed when user logins successfully  :

```
Ext.define('Eits.view.OrgTreeView', {
extend : 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
requires: ['Eits.model.OrgTreeModel'],
    width : '100%',
    region : 'center',
    border : true,
    user = this.localStorageProvider.get('name'),
    store : {
        xtype : 'tree',
        fields : Eits.model.OrgTreeModel.FIELDS,
        //model: 'Eits.model.OrgTreeModel',
        autoLoad: false,
        root: {
            id: 'rootNode',
            objectId : 'rootNode',
            leaf: false,
            expanded: false,
            text : this.user, 
            iconCls : 'mts-Tree-Node',
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'orgTree/getNavigationTree.action',
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'     
            }
        }
    },...
```

Is there a way that i could get the value from local storage and pass it as a name to tree's root.Also when I pass a static value to `text` field in the store's root , it does show the static value in my UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the creation of tree store inside `initComponent`:

```js
Ext.define('Eits.view.OrgTreeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
    requires: ['Eits.model.OrgTreeModel'],
    width: '100%',
    region: 'center',
    border: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            fields : Eits.model.OrgTreeModel.FIELDS,
            autoLoad: false,
            root: {
                id: 'rootNode',
                objectId : 'rootNode',
                leaf: false,
                expanded: false,
                text: localStorageProvider.get('name'), 
                iconCls: 'mts-Tree-Node',
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'orgTree/getNavigationTree.action',
                actionMethods: 'POST',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'     
                }
            }
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: It shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: localStorageProvider is not defined`  , The localstorage gets data after a successful login by the user.
I used  `this.localStorageProvider = Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider', {
    expires : null
   });` inside InitComponent .But it doesn't work either .Any wayout through this ?Thanks

Comment: The code sample I provided assumes that you either have the `localStorageProvider` variable available globally OR you would substitute it with whatever way you access your local storage. As you are saying "The localstorage gets data after a successful login" my understanding is that you *know* how to access it, don't you? If you don't, how then do you know that local storage gets data after login?

Comment: I have saved some data in my Browsers LocalStorage by using  `localStorageProvider.set('data',data);` once the user logs in successfully and now I am trying to use the same data in the treeView.js . How can I fetch the value saved in browsers localstorage in a view other than LoginVIew ? Thanks

Comment: In your LoginView, where does `localStorageProvider` come from? Just make it available within the tree exactly the same way. Or, you could save global reference to the local storage in LoginView e.g. `window.localStorage = localStorageProvider`. Then, in the tree's `initComponent` use `window.localStorage` instead of `localStorageProvider`.

Comment: I did set the localStorageProvider to window.localStorage in my loginController .... `window.localStorage=me.localStorageProvider;` where me is a scope variable .But i still cant access it in the treeView. `text: window.localStorage.get('name'), ` gives the following error :   http://gyazo.com/f8e40047e7b9b90c3be3a92cf2aaee2b  .Thanks

Comment: Oh.. Your app probably reloads the page when moving from LoginView to the tree? Then the global variable won't persist of course. In that case you need to find out how exactly `me.localStorageProvider` is populated in LoginView and populate it the same way in the tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80858/discussion-between-rawatdeepesh-and-drakees).

Comment: It worked by defining the localStorage variable in treeView,same way I did in the LoginView like you said . Thanks!